# Multiprocesamiento con procesos en Python

Tags: python, hilos

Debo escribir en un mismo archivo simultáneamente por 4 procesos, con hilos no tengo problema (incluso si no bloqueo el acceso, supongo que por el GIL), pero con procesos es distinto ya que al llegar a lock el proceso simplemente omite esa parte (esto lo supongo basado en el archivo de salida porque le faltan varias lineas), espero haberme explicado bien, adjunto gran parte del código.

```
def cruzar(archivo,ini,fin,tam,pos,num):
        with open(archivo,"r") as infile1:
            ant=''
            lin=0
            con=0
            lineas=conteo(archivo)
            progreso.pasos(1.0/lineas)
            infile=islice(infile1,ini,fin,None)
            for linea in infile:
                linex=linea.replace("\n", "")
                fila=re.split('[;|, ]',linex)
                if len(fila)>tam:
                    if ant!=fila[pos]:
                        con=buscar(fila[pos],cuentas)
                        ant=fila[pos]
                    if con==1:
                        lock.acquire()#Aquí es donde hago el bloqueo para los demás procesos
                        try:
                            outfile.write(linea)
                        finally:
                            lock.release()# pero en vez de esperar a que se desbloquee simplemente omite esas lineas



def escribir(l,linea):
    global outfile
    outfile.write(linea)
```

El mismo código me funciona usando Threads, solo cambio las declaraciones y ya, Traté de escribir todo el código posible, muchas gracias por la colaboración, quisiera saber qué tengo mal, por qué la diferencia .

Comment: Hola, Michael. Has puesto un código demasiado amplio. Hubiera sido mejor que lo hubieras acortado a un ejemplo mínimo que reproduzca el error que tienes, tal como se sugiere en el apartado ["Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable"](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) de la ayuda.

Comment: ...de hecho desconozco cómo llamas a este módulo, algo necesario para darte una respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una diferencia principal entre hilos y procesos es que los hilos comparten espacio de memoria mientras que los procesos tienen cada uno su espacio de memoria propio. Además de lo que comenta @mementum en su respuesta (pasar el candado como argumento a cada proceso) si imprimes la direccion de memoria de outfile en cada proceso verás que son objetos distintos, situados en distintos espacios de memoria. Esto causa que al abrir el archivo en modo `'w'` cada proceso termine reescribiendo el archivo, al final solo contiene la salida del último proceso en terminar. Una solución es que abras el archivo en modo `'append'`:

```
outfile = open(salida,"w")#crea el archivo que contendra el cruce
```

Se puede pasar a cada proceso la ruta del archivo y abrirlo en cada escritura, esto no es eficiente pero si cada proceso abre pocas veces el archivo puede servir. La duda es, ¿por qué no abrimos el archivo y le pasamos el objeto como argumento a cada subproceso como hacemos con el candado? Resulta que multiprocessing usa Pickle para serializar los datos y los objetos `io.TextIOWrapper` no son serializables.

No obstante, este tipo de implementaciones no son de mi agrado cuando se usan multiprocesos que requieren escribir en un mismo archivo. Hay otra aproximación siguendo el famoso 'Divide et impera' que no requiere del uso de candados y que evita dolores de cabeza y considero que es más seguro que habilitar el acceso de todos lo procesos a la escritura del archivo.

La idea es simple, crear un proceso que se encargue de escribir las salidas y que solo el pueda escribir en el archivo. Los demás procesos se encargan de hacer el trabajo y se comunican con el proceso de escritura mediante una cola. Cada proceso lee del archivo de origen, procesa los datos y coloca la salida en la cola de escritura. El proceso que se encarga de crear el archivo de salida va tomando la información de la cola y la guarda en el archivo. De esta forma separas la escritura en el archivo del procesamiento de datos, el programa sigue usando multiprocesos pero la escritura no es concurrente por lo que te evitas muchos problemas.

El problema que se nos plantea es que el proceso que se encarga de escribir las salidas en el archivo debe saber si los demás han terminado antes de terminar él. Debemos comunicar el estado entre procesos, esto se puede hacer de muchas formas desde eventos, memoria compartida o lo más simple, pasar una bandera acordada a la cola cuando un proceso termine para que el proceso que escribe la salida sepa que ha terminado:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, current_process
from time import sleep
from random import randint

def f(datos, cola):
    try:
        for n in datos:
            cola.put('{}x2={} --- Procesado por {}\n'.format(n,n*2,current_process().name))
            sleep(randint(1,100)/100)
    except: raise
    finally: cola.put('#end')

def write(ruta, cola, procesos):
    with open(ruta, 'w') as f:
        while procesos:
            data = cola.get()
            if data == '#end':
                procesos -= 1
            else:
                f.write(data)      


if __name__ == '__main__':
    datos = [0,25,145,98,25518,6868,15156,85,2,89879,64,]
    cola_escritura = Queue()
    output_path = 'salida.txt'

    workers = [Process(name = 'Proceso_{}'.format(i), target=f, args=(datos, cola_escritura,)) for i in range(4)]
    writer = Process(target = write, args=(output_path, cola_escritura, len(workers),))

    writer.start()
    for w in workers:
        w.start()

    writer.join()
    for w in workers:
        w.join()
```

El ejemplo es algo estúpido, solo es para mostrar la idea. Iniciamos 4 procesos que hacen las 'tareas duras' y 1 que se encarga de la escritura. Cada proceso recibe una lista con numeros, los procesa multiplicandolos por 2 y manda a la cola la operación y el nombre del proceso que la ha realizado. Para simular operaciones largas de procesar se usa `sleep` junto a un tiempo de espera aleatorio.

Todos los procesos comparten una cola de escritura donde envian las salidas para que sean escritas en el archivo. De esto se encarga el proceso `writer`. Cuando cada preceso termina envia `'#end'`  a la cola, esto se usa para que `writer` esté a la espera de recibir nuevos datos hasta que todos los procesos terminen.

Un archivo de salida sería algo así:

> 0x2=0 --- Procesado por Proceso_2
>   0x2=0 --- Procesado por Proceso_0
>   0x2=0 --- Procesado por Proceso_3
>   0x2=0 --- Procesado por Proceso_1
>   25x2=50 --- Procesado por Proceso_2
>   25x2=50 --- Procesado por Proceso_3
>   145x2=290 --- Procesado por Proceso_2
>   25x2=50 --- Procesado por Proceso_0
>   25x2=50 --- Procesado por Proceso_1
>   98x2=196 --- Procesado por Proceso_2
>   145x2=290 --- Procesado por Proceso_3
>   145x2=290 --- Procesado por Proceso_0
>   25518x2=51036 --- Procesado por Proceso_2
>   ...

Comment: Excelente, lo hice con Queue y me salió perfecto, tardé un poco en entender cómo funcionaba el código, pero me fue de mucha ayuda, saludos muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Dado que la pregunta menciona varias veces que el código funciona con `threading`, pero no con `multiprocessing`, asumamos:

- El `Lock` está siendo creado a nivel de módulo

Cuando se ejecutan *threads* en ese módulo, cada hilo tiene accesso a `lock` (que parece una variable de ámbito global) y manipulan el objeto.

En el caso de `multiprocessing`, el módulo se está ejecutando en distintos procesos y cada proceso tiene su propia variable global con su propia instancia de `Lock` en `lock`.

La solución:

- El proceso que inicia los demás procesos crea un `lock = multiprocessing.Lock`
- En la creación del proceso se pasa como argumento. `p = multiprocessing.Process(target=xxx, args=(lock,))`

Y se puede utilizar en la función `xxx`. También puede pasarse en las `kwargs` y acceder al `lock` por nombre.